# jQuery draggable and resizable panels

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have multiple 'bars' which I wish to resize and drag along a x-axis. You can compare it with a schedule representation.

You can see the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ene6C/5/

You can drag the bars, and you can resize the bars.

The problem is, that when you resize them, they slide behind other bars and I want them for each to stay on their current track.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could contain each draggable in a "row" like so...

http://jsfiddle.net/ene6C/8/

The problem you've got is the absolute positioning the jQuery applies to the dragged element. Adding a containing element that is positioned relatively should resolve this problem.